# Find out catalina home path of application

Tags: shell

I need a single line linux command to find out  catalina.home value.

Input:

```
# ps -aef | grep java
root      3953     1  1 04:39 pts/3    00:00:33 /usr/local/jdk1.6.0_14/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/MT_SMS_TN/conf/logging.properties -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+UseGCOverheadLimit -Xms512m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -server -ea -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=18075 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dorg.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.ENABLE_CLEAR_REFERENCES=false -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/var/MT_SMS_TN/endorsed -classpath :/var/MT_SMS_TN/bin/bootstrap.jar -Dcatalina.base=/var/MT_SMS_TN -Dcatalina.home=/var/MT_SMS_TN -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/MT_SMS_TN/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
root      4322  4321  0 Jan05 ?        00:00:01 /usr/java/jdk1.5.0_17/bin/java LiveUpdate [ -p Avenge MicroDefs25 SavCorp10 Linux -v MicroDefsB.Old -l SymAllLanguages -t HubDefs -z 100118039 ] [ -p Avenge MicroDefs25 SavCorp10 Linux -v MicroDefsB.Old -l SymAllLanguages -t CurDefs -z 100831002 ] [ -p Avenge MicroDefs25 SavCorp10 Linux -v MicroDefsB.CurDefs -l SymAllLanguages -t CurDefs -z 100831002 ]
root     11506  3826  0 05:34 pts/3    00:00:00 grep java
```

`-Dcatalina.home=/var/MT_SMS_TN` so the output should be:

```
/var/MT_SMS_TN
```

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: I want to print the value of catalina.home of  application process.

Comment: I know that. But what have you tried? Show some code. Not many people will be willing to help you if you don't show any effort.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by chaining two `awk` commands, something like:

```
ps aux | grep org.apache.catalina | awk -F'-Dcatalina.home=' '{print $2}' | awk '{print $1}'
```

The first command & `grep` extracts out the full process line for Catalina/Tomcat; the final parts split the string on the `catalina.home` directive and then extracts out the value portion